# How do I turn a SQL database downloaded table into a Google Sheets multi-line chart?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts

I want to turn this table (comes from an SQL database)

[image]

...into a line chart in Google Sheets that looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first you will need to pivot out series with **`QUERY`** formula and then plot the chart

  ```
  =QUERY(A1:C11, "select A,C,sum(C) where A is not null group by A,C pivot B", 1)
  ```

  [image: 0]